# Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Dynamic

default(Integer,Double)

a :: Num a => a
a = 5

-- show :: Show a => a -> String
-- toDyn :: Typeable a => a -> Dynamic

main :: IO ()
-- main = print $ show a -- *** THIS LINE WORKS WELL
main = print $ toDyn a   -- *** THIS LINE LEADS TO AN AMBIGUOUS TYPE ERROR
```

I don't understand why the first "main" version works, and not the second.
Is there someone who can help me ?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4):

> In situations where an ambiguous type is discovered, an ambiguous type variable, *v*, is defaultable if:
>
> - *v* appears only in constraints of the form *C v*, where *C* is a class, and
> - at least one of these classes is a numeric class, (that is, `Num` or a subclass of `Num)`, and
> - **all of these classes are defined in the Prelude or a standard library**

Your example fails because unlike `Show`, `Typeable` is not one of the classes specified in the third point, so no defaulting is performed.