# using "default" declaration for overloaded numeric operations

Tags: haskell

I try to develop an embedded domain specific language in Haskell.
I don't want to type signatures as `::Rational` all the time, so I try to use a default 
declaration for my types:

[corresponding section in Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls)

This works correctly in this simple example:

```
default (Integer, Double) -- "default default"

mag :: Float -> Float -> Float
mag x y = sqrt( x^2 + y^2 )

main = do

print $ mag 1 1
```

Indeed we obtain sqrt(2) as a result. If we replace the default declaration 
by:

```
default ()
```

, we obtain errors at compilation as expected: the type of `2` is ambiguous.

Now let us consider a more complicated example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Prelude hiding ((^^))
import Data.Ratio

default (Integer, Rational, Double)

class (Num a) => Foo a where
    (^^) :: Num b => b -> a -> b

instance Foo Rational where
    (^^) x r = x ^ n
        where n = 2*numerator r -- dummy calculation

instance Foo Integer where
    (^^) x n = x ^ n

mag :: Float -> Float -> Float
mag x y = sqrt( x ^^ 2 + y ^^ 2 )

main = do
print $ mag 1 1
```

I would expect it to work correctly, but we obtain errors concerning the 
ambiguous type of `2`.
Why?
How to make my default declaration work?
And if I want to give the priority to `Rational` instead of `Integer`? 
Indeed, this should be possible because we don't get any error below.

```
$ ghci
> import Data.Ratio
> 2::Rational
2 % 1
```

PS1: The answer may be related to

[answer given to a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120507/ambiguous-types-and-defaults-for-overloaded-numeric-operations)

but I don't know in which way.

PS2: I already asked the question one week ago on Haskell-Cafe:

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-September/108956.html

But as I obtained no answer, I ask the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell is very conservative about type class defaulting: it only chooses a default instance of classes defined in the Prelude.  In your case, there is a `Foo` constraint on the type of the literal 2, so the compiler won't choose a default instance for it.

You can declare types in a syntactically lighter way by writing monomorphic functions.  For example, the following compiles without errors:

```
rat :: Rational -> Rational
rat x = x

mag :: Float -> Float -> Float
mag x y = sqrt( x ^^ rat 2 + y ^^ rat 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks Heatsink for your answer. Isn't the typeclass constraint rather on the exponents (in my example, equal both to `2`)? Indeed the type variable `a` of the typeclass `Foo` corresponds to the exponent, not the base. Anyway, if I am right, the reason is thus that the right argument of `^^` has a typeclass constraint `Foo`, which is not a standard typeclass so no defaulting is possible. Am I right? Thanks for your solution.